# Transcription of a printed/handwritten certificate (3/4)

Tags: translation, german-to-english

I'd be very grateful for your comments[image]

Answer (score 3):

Der historische Verein Niedersachsen
unter dem Protektorat
Seiner Majestät
des Königs von Hannover
beurkundet
hiermit die geschehene Aufnahme
des Herrn Dr. Krahmer zu Moskau
als wirkliches (correspondierendes)
Mitglied
Hannover den 30. October 1862
Der Direktor des Vereins

Answer (score 3):

That's actually nicely printed and easily readable:

```
Der historische Verein für Niedersachsen
unter dem Protectorat
Seiner Majestät
des Königs von Hannover
beurkundet
hiermit die geschehene Aufnahme
des Herrn Dr. Krahmer zu Moskau
als wirkliches (-correspondierendes-)
Mitglied
Hannover den 30. October 1862
der Direktor des Vereines

[gezeichnet] Braun
```

Comment: Thank you all. Thats true that some prints lines are readable, but the lowest weren't
Does this document say that Doctor Krahmer has been sent to Moscow?
But is there any reason mentioned?

Comment: @АняКрамер It does not say that he was sent to Moscow. It is a certificate of admission  as a member of the historical society of the kingdom of  Lower Saxony.